# How to use jQuery to remove an item by its content within a list item

Tags: jquery

The CMS I am using is automatically spitting out a tag for alternate styling, which I want to remove from the DOM. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="recent-blog-posts-wrapper">

<ul>

<li class="widget-alternate-item tag-Middle-Tennessee-SE">

<div class="tag-wrapper">
<a class="tag">widget alternate item</a>
<a class="tag">Middle Tennessee SE</a>
</div> 

</li>            
</ul>
```

I want to remove only the first tag, containing the content "widget alternate item" while keeping the other tag(s) in the group. The "widget alternate item" only appears on alternating list items, so a::first pseudo class won't work.

The following script is not pulling an error but is also not removing the item. Using underscores vs empty spaces between the content words has no effect; I've tried it both ways.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {                
        $('.recent-blog-posts-wrapper li .tag-wrapper a.tag:contains("widget_alternate_item")').empty();
         })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mohamed-Yousef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3385827/mohamed-yousef)'s solution is working, but what happens if, for some reason, your `widget alternate item` is not the first one in the list? If the content matters more than the position, you would be better off using `.each()` and `.text()`...

```js
$(function () {  
  $('.tag', '.recent-blog-posts-wrapper').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.text() === 'widget alternate item') {
      $this.remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="recent-blog-posts-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="widget-alternate-item tag-Middle-Tennessee-SE">
      <div class="tag-wrapper">
        <a class="tag">widget alternate item</a>
        <a class="tag">Middle Tennessee SE</a>
      </div> 
    </li>            
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @MikeRapp: Cool! If you think your problem is now solved, do not forget to accept an answer (Mohamed's answer or mine) to "close" this question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use css `:eq()` or jquery `.eq()` and jquery `.remove()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {                
        $('.recent-blog-posts-wrapper li .tag-wrapper a.tag:contains("widget alternate item"):eq(0)').remove();
         })
</script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {                
    $('.recent-blog-posts-wrapper li .tag-wrapper a.tag:contains("widget alternate item"):eq(0)').remove();
});
```

```css
a{
  display : block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="recent-blog-posts-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="widget-alternate-item tag-Middle-Tennessee-SE">
      <div class="tag-wrapper">
        <a class="tag">widget alternate item</a>
        <a class="tag">Middle Tennessee SE</a>
        <a class="tag">widget item</a>
        <a class="tag">widget alternate item</a>
      </div> 
    </li>            
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Additional**: if you have more `li`s you'll need to use `.filter()`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {                
    $('.recent-blog-posts-wrapper li .tag-wrapper a.tag:contains("widget alternate item")').filter(function(){ return $(this).index() == 0}).remove();
});
```

```css
a{
  display : block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="recent-blog-posts-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="widget-alternate-item tag-Middle-Tennessee-SE">
      <div class="tag-wrapper">
        <a class="tag">widget alternate item</a>
        <a class="tag">Middle Tennessee SE</a>
        <a class="tag">widget alternate item</a>
        <a class="tag">widget alternate item</a>
      </div> 
    </li>
    <li class="widget-alternate-item tag-Middle-Tennessee-SE">
      <div class="tag-wrapper">
        <a class="tag">widget alternate item</a>
        <a class="tag">Middle Tennessee SE</a>
        <a class="tag">widget alternate item</a>
        <a class="tag">widget alternate item</a>
      </div> 
    </li>     
  </ul>
</div>
```

> Note: the `.filter()` code will not work correctly if your element is
>   not the first child of `tag-wrapper`